# Building a backup server

Tags: central-processing-unit, hardware, backup

One of my older motherboards broke and I'm planning to use the remaining power supply, hard drive and case to build a backup server. I want to buy a new motherboard and CPU that can be used 24x7 and wont break down in a few months.

So the question is, do you have any recommendations on any reliable motherboards and CPU for a backup server? Processing power is not a huge issue.

Comment: You might have better luck on superuser.com. This is a place for systems administrators, so you'll likely get that perspective and it doesn't fit given the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the CPU, go for something low-power like an Atom then you have less cooling issues which is one of the main reasons a CPU (and a machine in general) can have problems.

Motherboard decisions will be limited by your CPU choice somewhat, though avoid anything "fancy" - for a simple backup server you don't need all the bells and whistles so if you spend extra spend on quality rather than features. I don't have any specific advise on what constitutes quality here though.

(and as MakM says, you might get more/better answers to this question over on SU)

Answer (score 0):

Depends of the backup volume..

- good and multiple Ethernet ports.
- quickest disks as possible for buffering (SATA 10K or SAS drives): more platter, better performance
- many SATA or SAS controllers

A backup server have to manage a lot of IO, some memory, but not much processing power.